# Numeric implicity in Scala.js

Tags: scala, implicit, scala.js

I want to work with Numeric in scala.js. I need to use Numeric implicity in some of the functions (library to which I add scala.js already have it). For example for this code:

```
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.{JSExport, JSExportTopLevel}

@JSExportTopLevel("NumericOps")
class JsNumericOps[V] {
  @JSExport("add")
  def add(x: V, y: V)(implicit num: Numeric[V]): V = {
    num.plus(x, y)
  }
}

class NumericOps[V: Numeric] {
  def add(x: V, y: V)(implicit num: Numeric[V]): V = {
    num.plus(x, y)
  }
}
```

After that I run it in javascript console:

```
NumericOps().add(3,3)
```

And get errors:

> scalajsenv.js:211 Uncaught $c_sjsr_UndefinedBehaviorError {s$1: "An
>   undefined behavior was detected: undefined is not an instance of
>   scala.math.Numeric", e$1: $c_jl_ClassCastException, stackTrace$1:
>   null, stackdata: $c_sjsr_UndefinedBehaviorError, stack: "Error↵    at
>   $c_sjsr_UndefinedBehaviorError.$c_jl_…ndpit-fastopt.js:1188:15)↵    at
>   :1:14"}

What is the right way to use Numeric[T] implicity in scala.js?

Comment: You cannot use type classes (like `Numeric[T]`) from JavaScript. Within Scala.js the usage is no different than in Scala for the JVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of an `implicit Numeric[T]` would make sense if you were not interoperating with JavaScript. Within Scala code, implicits work the same as in Scala. But when interoperating with JavaScript, implicit parameters become fully *explicit*: JavaScript does not have a typechecker with implicit resolution to fill in the missing parameters, so even implicit parameters need to be provided at call site in JS.

Obviously, this is not what you want. In fact, unless you exported a reference to the relevant instances of `Numeric`, the JavaScript code would not even be able to pass them as parameters.

Instead, you need to only export methods that do not need `Numeric[T]` parameters, which means that you will need to *overload* your method `add` for all possible JS numeric types. You're in luck here, though: JS only has *one* `number` type, and it translates to `Double` in Scala.js. Therefore, all you need to do is to only deal with `Double`s in `JsNumericOps`:

```
@JSExportTopLevel("NumericOps")
class JsNumericOps {
  @JSExport
  def add(x: Double, y: Double): Double = {
    x + y
  }
}
```

while keeping `NumericOps` generic and with the relevant `Numeric` implicits.

If you want to reuse implementations from `NumericOps` within `JsNumbericOps`, you can very easily do so:

```
@JSExportTopLevel("NumericOps")
class JsNumericOps {
  private val numericOps = new NumericOps

  @JSExport
  def add(x: Double, y: Double): Double = {
    numericOps.add(x, y)
  }
}
```

Here, the Scala compiler will infer the `implicit Numeric[Double]` that needs to be given to `numericOps.add(x, y)`, within `JsNumericOps.add`. The JavaScript code will never need to see that, which is an implementation detail of `JsNumericOps.add`.

Comment: This is a great answer, You help me a lot. But I see that I attach a little wrong piece of code, which change a little sense of my issue. In JsNumericOps I want to use NumericOps(I do not want rewrite solution, which is much more complex in library with which I work..)

Comment: @KubaWenta I have expanded the answer for `JsNumericOps` to reuse `NumericOps`.